# Multiple max results

Tags: mysql, sql

Table structure

```
id (p) | date | id2 (fk) | id3 (fk)
```

where (p) is primary id and (fk) is foreign key

This query returns a list of latest unique rows

```
select
    max(date) as date1,
    id1,
    id2
from `table`
group by id1, id2
```

I would also like to have the second date in a row, which have to be the second highest date

Something like

```
select
    max(date) as date1,
    max_second(date) as date2,
    id1,
    id2
from `table`
group by id1, id2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Join the table to itself, matching the id columns but (and this is the key) matching where the joined table's rows have dates less than the main table's rows.

```
select
    max(t1.date) as date1,
    max(t2.date) as date2,
    t1.id2,
    t1.id2
from `table` t1
left join `table` t2 on t2.id1 = t1.id1 and t2.id2 = t1.id2 and t2.date < t1.date
group by id1, id2;
```

Note that `date2` may `null` if there are no rows for a previous date (hence the need for a `left join`)

This query will take forever unless you have an index on id1 and/or id2.
For maximum speed, do this:

```
create index table_id1_id2 on `table`(id1, id2);
```

and if that's not fast enough, try the speed after running this:

```
create index table_id1_id2_date on `table`(id1, id2, date);
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Though it takes almost forever to complete this query

Comment: ...now it's like a rocket) Thanks again